# Indirect() volatility : do not trigger if

Tags: vba, excel, volatile, excel-indirect

I need to use the indirect function in a formula because it refers to a sheet 2 that can be deleted.
I do not want to trigger Indirect function when it's not needed, due to its volatility. So I write this formula :

```
=IF(abc=1;"";INDIRECT("Sheet 2!zzz"))
```

I have the result I want ("" or zzz value).
But it seems to be always volatile !
I used this macro to test it (found on http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm) :

```
Option Base 1
Option Compare Text
'-----------------------
Public jCalcSeq As Long             ''' calculation sequence counter
'
Public Function CalcSeqCountRef(theRange As Range) As Variant
    '
    ' COPYRIGHT © DECISION MODELS LIMITED 2000. All rights reserved
    '
    ' increment calculation sequence counter at Full Recalc or when theRange changes
    ' fixed for false dependency
    '
    jCalcSeq = jCalcSeq + 1
    CalcSeqCountRef = jCalcSeq + (theRange = theRange) + 1
    Debug.Print Application.Caller.Formula
End Function
Sub resetcounter()
    jCalcSeq = 0
End Sub
```

How could I write this formula to not be volatile ?

Thank you :).

Comment: If a sheet is missing, the formula should return an error, so using `IFERROR` should do what you want.

Comment: Since `...  + (theRange = theRange) + 1` always resolves to zero, what is its purpose?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad : not neccessary, because if my sheet 2 is missing that's the "" that is selected.

Comment: @Jeeped : that's a macro I found on http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm It seems to work pretty well. Did you test it on formulas you know as volatile and not volatile ?

Comment: @Jeeped: The UDF can be used to trace Excel's calculation sequence and needs a reference to the range inside the function to avoid the UDF falling into the false dependency trap and possibly executing out of sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make formula containing a volatile function not behave volatile even with IF or CHOOSE etc: the formula is flagged as volatile if it contains a volatile function or a name that refers to a volatile function.

Comment: Thank you ! I missed this in your wonderfull page about volatility :
"=IF(1<2,99,NOW()) will always return 99 and the volatile NOW() function will never be called, but the cell containing the IF formula will be treated as volatile, (thanks to Stephen Bullen for pointing this out)."

Is there any solution to not use volatile function in my case (sheet deleted and I need to keep the formulas intact) ?

ps : your macro is a dream for me. I used it a lot to earadicate volatile functions in my sheets !!

Comment: If I understand what you want you could use IFERROR(Sheet2!zzz,"")

Comment: I have 2 sheets.
On Sheet 1, in cell A1 I have "=IFERROR(Sheet2!zzz,"")
On Sheet 2, cell A1 name is "zzz" (in the name manage zzz scope is Sheet 2, not workbook).
When I delete Sheet 2, the formula in Sheet1!A1 changes to "=IFERROR(Workbook1!zzz,"").
So when I create again Sheet2, the formula doesn't work anymore.

Is there only INDIRECT() to keep formulas in this scenario ?

Comment: do you have any idea please ?

Comment: Try using a global Name rather than a local one: I think that should work - but when you add sheet2 back again you have to recreate the global name

Comment: Well, it won't work that way because I need names to be local (scope to worksheet) for another reason. I resolve my problem by writting formulas in VBA when needed. That not the perfect solution but it will work. Thank you very much for your help !!